# No embedded stylesheet instruction for file

Tags: java, xml, github, web-crawler

I wanted to learn more about crawlers and find a [project](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) on **git** which I didn't know how to use until yesterday. I finally achieved to import it to eclipse but now it is giving the following:

```
07:45:07,798 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null
07:45:07,811 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\st\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\jre\lib\endorsed
07:45:07,840 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: C:\Users\st\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml
07:45:08,019 FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/st/git/crawler_new/pom.xml

org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/st/git/crawler_new/pom.xml
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:225)
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:186)
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:73)

Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/st/git/crawler_new/pom.xml
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:214)
... 2 more
```

According to searches I have done for the error, it looks like the error is related to xml file but I don't know much about xml. But the `pom.xml` file that is not found is sitting in the directory `/C:/Users/st/git/crawler_new/pom.xml`.

Also, I searched in the [issues](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues) in project's git site but couldn't find anything related to my problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to "run" the POM file in Eclipse (Run As/XSL transformation or whatever the option is) in which case Eclipse is trying to find an XSL stylesheet to transform the XML - not what you're interested in.  The POM file is a file for a tool called [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) which specifies a project's structure, its dependencies, etc.  You first want to download Maven and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from the command line/shell which will generate all of the Eclipse meta-data files for the project (e.g. `.project`, `.classpath`, etc) and re-import your project as a Java application.  Alternatively, download the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin and import it as a Maven project.

Maven may take a bit to learn but there are many tutorials available aside from the one on the Maven site, simply google it.

Comment: I have eGit, is there similar option for egit like `mvn eclipse:eclipse`? I was thinking of whether I have imported to eclipse properly

Comment: No, eGit is a tool to integrate Eclipse with git.  Maven is (among other things) a build tool.  When you imported your project, did you have to go and manually add a bunch of jars to get it to compile?  Maven takes care of that stuff for you.  You can get the project working without Maven and do it all manually but if that's what you want to do, you have absolutely no need for that POM file.

Comment: As an aside, trust me, maven is very nice.  Using Maven (and git), I'm able to checkout the project and get it in Eclipse (without compile errors) in less than a minute.  Without Maven, I'm assuming you had to go download a bunch of jars yourself to get it to compile (e.g HttpCore, Sleepycat, etc). Maven handles all of that.

Comment: This is what I was having problem, I've been working on to create runnable java project. thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

In STS, right click on the entry point java file -> Run as -> Java Application.

Then the error "No embedded stylesheet instruction for file" disappeared. It work fine to me.